# Qt invoking qml function with custom QObject type

Tags: c++, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I want to invoke a qml method from c++ passing as a parameter a custom type.

This is my custom type (*Note that all the code I post is not exactly what i'm using, i've extracted the relevant parts, so if you try to compile it is possible that some changes have to be made)

Custom.h

```
class Custom : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(QString ssid READ getSSID WRITE setSSID)

public:

Q_INVOKABLE const QString& getSSID() {
        return m_ssid;
    }
     Q_INVOKABLE void setSSID(const QString& ssid) {
        m_ssid = ssid;
    }
}

private:
    QString m_ssid;
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(NetworkInfo)
```

Custom.cpp

```
Custom::Custom(): QObject() {
    setSSID("ABC");
}


Custom::Custom(const Custom & other): QObject() {
    setSSID(other.getSSID());
}
```

This is where I call the qml method

```
void MyClass::myMethod(const Custom &custom) {
      QMetaObject::invokeMethod(&m_item,
                              "qmlMethod", Q_ARG(QVariant, QVariant::fromValue(custom)));
}
```

where `QQuickItem& m_item`

I have declared Custom as QML and QT meta types

```
qmlRegisterType<Custom>("com.mycustom", 1, 0, "Custom");
```

When i try to access the parameter inside the qml

```
import com.mycustom 1.0

function(custom) {
    console.log(custom.ssid)
}
```

I get

```
qml: undefined
```

If i do `console.log(custom)` I get

```
qml: QVariant(Custom)
```

so, i'd say my type is correctly imported into Qt (I have used it without problems instantiating it directly in Qml with

```
Custom {
 ....
}
```

Now, the question :)

Why can't I access the ssid property ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you seem to have registered everything correctly, you might be encounting a bug that sometimes happen with QML where objects seem to be stuck in a QVariant wrapping. Try the following and see if it work.

```
import com.mycustom 1.0

property QtObject temp

function(custom) {
    temp = custom;
    console.log(temp.ssid);
}
```

Sometimes forcing your instance to be a QtObject will remove the annoying "QVariant wrapper" and solve the issue.