# Qt 5.7 - C++ Signal / QML Slot - Custom Meta type wrapped in QVariant

Tags: qt, qml, signals, slot, metatype

I'm trying to connect a C++ signal to a QML slot. The exchanged data is a constant reference to an object of my own class. Thereby this class is registered to the Qt meta system, before the QML file is loaded.

In code it looks like this:

The header of the **custom meta type**:

```
class QSong : public QObject
{

    private:

        Q_OBJECT

        Q_PROPERTY( QString artist READ artist CONSTANT )
        Q_PROPERTY( QString album READ album CONSTANT )
        Q_PROPERTY( QString title READ title CONSTANT)

        QString m_artist;   ///<  Data field containing the song's artist
        QString m_album;    ///<  Data field containing the song's album
        QString m_title;    ///<  Data field containing the song's title


    public:

        /* Constructors, copy assignment operator and getters */

};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QSong)
```

The **meta type registration** (Before loading the qml file):

```
qmlRegisterType<QSong>("webradio.types", 1, 0, "Song");
```

The **C++ signal**:

```
void currentSongChanged( const QSong& song );
```

The **QML slot**:

```
Connections {
    target: Global.MPD;      // This is a tested to be working singleton
    onCurrentSongChanged: {
        print(song);
        print(song.artist);
    }
}
```

As far as I understood the procedure, this should be sufficient for transferring the data. Still whenever the signal is triggered with a valid QSong object, the output is the following:

```
qml: QVariant(QSong)
qml: undefined
```

I know similar questions have been asked before, however the solutions stated there have not worked for me.

For instance if I try assigning the slot parameter to a local property as suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23271195/qt-invoking-qml-function-with-custom-qobject-type), the output states

```
Cannot assign QSong to QSong*
```

I'm using Qt 5.7.1 with the GCC at version 6.2.1.

Comment: You don't need `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QSong)` that doesn't work for `QObject` derived types, it shouldn't even compile. Try `void currentSongChanged(QSong * song );` instead, it should work. You may have to `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QSong*)`.

Comment: That helped me out for now, thanks. However how does the memory management work in this case? Can I allocate the QSong object on the stack / safely delete the heap instance, after the signal was emitted?

Comment: Allocate on the heap, delete only after you no longer need the object. If you pass an object to QML and then delete it, when you try to use it from QML the app will crash.

Comment: If you don't need any slots or signals on `QSong`, I would suggest using a non-QObject class instead, with the `Q_GADGET` marker to provide the property access.

If you add a `Q_INVOKABLE toString() const` to that class it will be called by the JavaScript environment whenever it needs to get the string representation of the object, such as your `print(song)` call

Comment: Is the only possibility to use reference (QSong*) in the signal. is there no way to use QSong as argument ?